# password Sha hash login

Tags: php, session

during registeration, i hashed and salt password using SHA 512

as follows

```
// Create a random salt
$salt = hash('sha512', uniqid(mt_rand(1, mt_getrandmax()), true));
// Create salted password (Careful not to over season)
$pass = hash('sha512', $pass.$salt);
```

salt and pass are stored in database. but i don't know how to create login form using hashed and salted password. can anyone help me below is my login form

```
//session_start();

if (
    isset($_POST['username']) &&
    isset($_POST['pass']) &&
    !empty($_POST['username']) &&
    !empty($_POST['pass'])

) {

    $db = new PDO(
        'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=timeline', // dsn

        'root', // username
        '' // password
    );


    $statement = $db->prepare('
        SELECT * FROM users
        WHERE username = ?
        AND password = ?

    ');

    $statement->execute(array(
        $_POST['username'],
        $_POST['pass']

    ));

    if ($row = $statement->fetch()) {

        $_SESSION['sess_user'] = $row['uid'];

        $_SESSION['sess_name'] = $row['username'];
        include('success.php');


    } else include('fail.php');

} else include('fail.php');
```

Comment: We need more information: where is the salt? Where is the hash?

Comment: You should use the new [Password Hashing extension](http://php.net/manual/en/book.password.php). If you have PHP <5.5.0 then use the [compatibility library](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat). Also, you need to explain in more detail what it is you are trying to do -- it is not quite clear as it stands right now.

Answer (score 0):

You have to store the salt in your database along with the username and the password hash.

Query the database (using a `WHERE` condition on the username) to retrieve the salt and the password hash. Compute the password hash, and compare it to the password hash you retrieved from the database.

---

Bonus points for doing a constant time compare.

Comment: that is just my problem, can you just give example in the query statement, please